# Node Red HTML node to see Inspect instead of View Source

Tags: html, css, node-red

I am trying to have node red go to my router IP and search through the HTML code to see whether a certain device is on the list. When I right click - inspect I can hover over the list I am interested in and see the HTML information I am looking for. When I use the HTML node it seems to only look through the view page source information, which does not have what I am looking for. I there a way to point the HTML node at a more specific element instead of the page source as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data in the page on your router might be dynamically generated using JavaScript.

This means that when the page is loaded it only has the outline and the rest is filled in by the code using XHResquests to a  different URL that supplies the information.

In order for Node-RED to be able to extract the information from the page it would need to load the outline, then effectively run all the JavaScript. Libraries like PhantomJS

There is a contrib node that might be able to help [node-red-contrib-nbrowser](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-nbrowser) but the better approach would probably be to work out what URL the JavaScript is calling and calling that directly as the data is most likely to be in a format that is easier to process (e.g. JSON)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to go further and find the url (I think) I should be looking. Node-red pulls in information and I can follow along with its output compared to the inspect tool on the browser, but it does not show every layer of the code. I can see the exact location my info should be but it does not drop down that tab.  I have "*" as my Selector in the HTML Node which I thought would display everything.

Comment: If you're unsure about the URL, you should be able to use the Developer Tools in the browser to find it. Open it up and go to the Network tab, then browse to the router page and note all the URL requests it makes. Copy any likely candidates into another browser window and see which one gives you the data you need. However - what data are you trying to get? If it's to just find devices connected to the network, something like `node-red-contrib-nmap` might help (haven't used it myself).

Comment: Yeah that "stok=..." looks suspiciously like an authentication token. And Googling "luci" from the URL suggests you may have an OpenWrt modem. So I think your options are `node-red-contrib-nbrowser` or `node-red-contrib-nmap` or the OpenWrt API (I have no experience with this).